# MessageBox Inside Updatepanel is not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

The Messagebox code in c# i've used is the following code,which is call conditionally based on my requirement.It works fine in all cases except when the Ajax update panel is used.
For example i would like to prompt the user if no check box is selected in a gridview,with 
appropriate message,The code is executed but no message box is displayed

```
 public static void MessageBox(string message, Page page)
    {       
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">" + "alert('" + message + "'); " + "</script>";
            page.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Im Hari: why don't you try Asynchronous auto post back, and check its working or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as suggested [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1076549.aspx/1)

Answer (score 2):

Use **ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock** or **ClientScriptManager .RegisterClientScriptBlock** method to add your script while using update panel.

An example of this is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adding the label directly onto the page. This will work fine for full post-back scenarios (and you mention it does), but if you don't add it somewhere directly inside the UpdatePanel, it won't get written to the page on the partial postback.

Answer (score 1):

i was also looking for a same kind of solution, since i had the same problem.the below method worked for me as @Sids suggested..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(myControl, myControl.GetType(), "msg", "alert('Success')", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, an Ajax postback inside an UpdatePanel only manipulates the HTML inside the UpdatePanel using some ASP.Net Ajax JavaScript magic. If you add JavaScript code inside the updated HTML, it will not get executed.

Why don't you use a CustomValidator to verify your checkboxes?